# Create adjacency matrix from array and its transpose

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, adjacency-matrix

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:
[image]

And I would like to create a symmetrical matrix like this:
[image]

Where the value is actually the length of the intersection of the two lists. Therefore I have made this function:

```
 def intersectSize(l1, l2):
     return len(set(l1) & set(l2))
```

Is there a function out there that would resemble this one:

```
def createSymMatrix(array, func):
    ...
    return matrix
```

where `array` is my initial dataframe and `func` is the `intersectSize` function?

**EDIT:** figured it out with this two liner:

```
array = [[len(set(l1)&set(l2)) for l1 in df]] for l2 in df]
adj = pd.DataFrame(data=array, index=df.index, columns=df.index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this,

```
r=[]
for val in list(itertools.product(df[0].values,df[0].values)):
    r.append( len(set(val[0])&set(val[1])) )
print pd.DataFrame(np.array(r).reshape(len(df),-1))
```

Using List Comprehension:

```
t= [len(set(val[0])&set(val[1])) for val in list(itertools.product(df[0].values,df[0].values))]
print pd.DataFrame(np.array(t).reshape(len(df),-1))
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  3  0  0  1
1  0  1  0  1
2  0  0  2  0
3  1  1  0  2
```